# Python print file name from a Data class

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to print a filename from a class. The class is defined in here in the below code. The code runs without any issues but it doesn't print the filename, my guess is that i have an issue with calling the class.

I am trying to call the class in another file to print the file name into a CSV during training, and using this code to do this:

```
filename=CellsDataset(args.data_dir,transform=ToTensor(),return_filenames=True)
print(filename)
```

Comment: Can you share what `print(filename)` shows

Comment: <dataset2.CellsDataset object at 0x7ffd771361d0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CellsDataSet contains a list of filenames in its `files` attribute, so you can print all of them like this:

```
filename=CellsDataset(args.data_dir,transform=ToTensor(),return_filenames=True)
print(filename.files)
```